# How to hide a python Command Prompt window

Tags: python, linux, windows, terminal

I am working on a program where the user types how old they are. Which is a `raw_input` string. Once they hit the enter button. So after the user gives me their input. I want the program to go away and run in the background. And if possible I would like to know how to do this in Windows & Linux systems.

```
hi = raw_input("How old are you? ")
```

Comment: Please explain your goal.

Comment: @Eric he wants to hide the terminal window after accepting some input.

Comment: @RishavKundu : yes but why?

Comment: @EricLevieil I re typed the question so you could understand it better. Making it more clear as to what my goal is.

Comment: @EricLevieil I want it to run in the background like why most programs do. To run things like server connections saving and reading data.

Comment: @Eric I don’t think the “why” is important. Just whether it is possible or not.

Comment: A GUI application makes sense, a terminal application too, but why do you want a mix?

Comment: @EricLevieil I know a GUI application this is easy I have done this many times with a GUI. But I am developing a early Alpha Version of my program and I do not want to add the GUI yet. The example above is just a random example and not my actual application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, you can use:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.kernel32.FreeConsole()
```

Given that you started it by a double-click and not from the console.

For a better solution, I would suggest running the script using `pythonw.exe` and using a GUI library (`tkinter` or something fancier) to display a dialog box instead.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in linux and windows?

Comment: Thank you this is basically what I was asking for!

Comment: Does the shell even pop-up in linux?

Comment: A problem with using `FreeConsole` from an interactive command prompt is that cmd.exe waits for the process to exit. An alternative is to use the `subprocess` module to respawn the script using `creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS`, i.e. a flags value of 8. The script knows it's detached if `ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow() == 0`.